# Unread mail count on iPhone / iPad is often out of date

Tags: iphone, mail.app, mobileme

Apparently, data is only pushed to the iPhone when a new unread emails arrives. 
If you read an email on your desktop or on the web, the 'Read' status is not being pushed down to the iPhone until another new email is being pushed down or you check manually.

It's very annoying because I always think there are new messages when there aren't, and the only way to find out is to launch Mail.

Is there a solution?

Comment: This is not my experience using Google Mail via Exchange to allow push. What type of account/server are you using? This might be specific to the email service you're using...?

Comment: Same here, Google Mail via Exchange to allow push. I get read and unread messages pushed to the phone. (iPhone 3GS)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **No**

As far as Apple is concerned this is by design, and even the latest mail upgrade on MobileMe did not enable this functionality. This has been discussed at length on the Apple forums and hopefully at some point this change will be made.

There is no known workaround, as this is controlled by the server, and not the local app. Even jailbroken their is no solution I am aware of.

Comment: I find it hilarious that this doesn't work with Apple's own mail system but it works very well indeed with Gmail using the Exchange settings.

Comment: This doesn't in fact work with Gmail. I switched from Gmail to MobileMe hoping this problem would disappear.